How do I make pip look at sources specified in toml file?
I'm trying to build a python package that contains an external dependency hosted on a private repo. I'm using poetry for packaging and dependency management. Although I specified the repo in the .toml file, when I try to install the generated .wheel (poetry build), pip is not looking in my private repo.How can I fix this?
pyproject.toml
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "mySource"
url = "https://url/to/myRepo"
priority = "explicit"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
myPackage = { version = "*", source = "mySource" }

pip log
pip install --force-reinstall -vv .myLib-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
...
1 location(s) to search for versions of myLib:
* https://pypi.org/simple/myPackage/
Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/myPackage/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/myPackage/
Found index url https://pypi.org/simple/
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/myPackage/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
No cache entry available
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/myPackage/ HTTP/1.1" 404 13
Status code 404 not in (200, 203, 300, 301, 308)
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/myPackage/: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/myPackage/ - skipping
Skipping link: not a file: https://pypi.org/simple/myPackage/
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'myPackage': discarding no candidates
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of myLib to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Will try a different candidate, due to conflict:
    myLib 0.1.0 depends on myPackage
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement myPackage (from myLib) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for myPackage


Probably because you have tool.poetry.source in your toml file. So, if you do poetry install it should work I guess.
